# error: cannot find symbol import my.package.name.Class

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I had worked on a github library but I had to implement it by placing its files in my project. I have downloaded the files and implemented them in my project. Now everything is fine in the code, there are no compile errors but when I am trying to run my Application, I am facing these types of errors:

[Errors in the build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKKjj.png)

The activity import code is fine:

[Fine Activity Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5o6p.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following repo to your project

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url  "https://dl.bintray.com/crysis21/Android"
    }
}
```

Add the following dependency to your project:

```
implementation 'com.hold1:keyboardheightprovider:0.0.9'
```

Comment: I was facing errors when I had these lines in my gradle files. So I downloaded the files from Github and placed them in my project.